Fusion 360 Board Panelization
I'm working on panelizing a PCB designed in Fusion 360. While I'm aware of external tools for panelizing Gerber files, I'd like to explore options within Fusion 360.
Does anyone know if Fusion 360 currently offer a built-in panelization feature?  Alternatively, are there any User Defined Scripts (ULPs) or training documents available to guide me through the panelization process within the software?
Ideally, I'd like to panelize not only the PCB layout but also the assembly file and Bill of Materials (BOM).

There was panelize.ulp back when it was eagle. That basically copied the component names to a different layer then copied and pasted them IIRC. But it was a bit clunky and no good for BoMs. No idea if fusion has it.
